# How to apply outer border for a GraphicsPath

Tags: c#, winforms

How to apply outer border for a GraphicsPath??
I tried the below code but it applies border to the individual rectangles instead of the whole path.

**My Expected output screenshot is below.**

[image]

**Runnable Sample Which I tried :**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.Form1_Paint);
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        GraphicsPath graphicsPath = new GraphicsPath();

        Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(20, 20, 100, 30);
        Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(20, 50, 40, 20);

        graphicsPath.StartFigure();
        graphicsPath.AddRectangle(rect1);
        graphicsPath.AddRectangle(rect2);

        graphicsPath.CloseAllFigures();
        e.Graphics.FillPath(Brushes.LightGreen, graphicsPath);
        e.Graphics.DrawPath(Pens.DarkGreen, graphicsPath);

    }
}
```

**Please suggests me how to achieve my expected output. Thanks in Advance.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drawing the shape using a polygon instead of rectangles achieves the desired result:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.Form1_Paint);
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        GraphicsPath graphicsPath = new GraphicsPath();
        Point[] pts = new Point[] { new Point(20, 20), 
                                    new Point(120, 20), 
                                    new Point(120, 50), 
                                    new Point(60, 50),        
                                    new Point(60, 70), 
                                    new Point(20, 70) };

        graphicsPath.AddPolygon(pts);

        e.Graphics.FillPath(Brushes.LightGreen, graphicsPath);
        e.Graphics.DrawPath(Pens.DarkGreen, graphicsPath);
    }
}
```